# Failed to start Snappy Daemon

Tags: boot, grub2, snap

Tried restarting my computer and while it's booting Ubuntu 18.04, it gets hung up after:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Snappy daemon,
See 'systemct1 status snapd.service' for details,
```

Comment: see if you can `ctrl-c` during the process? I've encountered the same issue and it seems like it skips through to the rest of the boot after. If you make it through, run the command `journalctl -u snapd.service` and include the output.

Comment: Could you add detailed log, it would help to narrow down issue. I have come across few links (appended at end of message) which could lead to possible solution, or at least provide a direction to find the resolution. Few links for starters... [What is snapd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963404/what-do-snap-snapd-and-snappy-refer-to#963415), [Similar issue but more related to connectivity crash.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998057/unable-to-connect-to-snappy-or-run-snappy-commands-on-ubuntu-17-10), [SnapCraft](https://forum.snapcraft.io/latest)

Comment: Run this very command and post output of it in Your question : ` sudo systemctl status snapd.service`.

Comment: Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1095343/212930) and if it fails, run the command: `sudo systemctl status snapd.service` - although I'm sure this is solved, and we can close this off ;)

Comment: what does systemctl status snapd.service give you ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1779961) that reflect the issue you are describing. However, the bug report indicates that, at the base level, the issue is with the kernel. So if you're not running the latest kernel, which you can check by running `uname -r` (I am on 18.04.05 using kernel `5.4.0-58-generic`), you may want to attempt upgrading:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

if that does not solve the issue you may want to uninstall/reinstall snap:
Find installed snaps: `snap list`

1. Remove installed snaps: `sudo snap remove <packages-from-snap-list>`
2. Remove snapd: `sudo apt purge snapd`
3. Remove snap directory from home: `rm -rf ~/snap`

   If you receive an error removing snapd then do the following:

   ```bash
   sudo rm -rf /var/cache/snapd 
   sudo apt purge snapd
   ```

Comment: Related: [How to completely remove snap and replace with flatpak?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1384366/349837)