# Loop in "failed to start Snappy Daemon"

Tags: boot, 18.04, snap

I'm not really experienced with Ubuntu and do not have a clue what to do in the current situation.

My system currently has two boot states:

1. Does not boot at all. Going to different console by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> shows that it tries to start Snappy daemon in the loop. It waits for it to be started for 90 seconds, then stops it and tries to start again.

   [snapd.service log](https://pastebin.com/RLX0HbFW)
2. Fails to start GUI, but different console <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> loads terminal where I can execute commands. I'm not sure exactly how to go into that state from the first one. Perhaps by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> several times sometimes helps after restart.

   [syslog](https://pastebin.com/Gu8rgKb8)

In the second state it complains about:

```
WARNING: IceLockAuthFile failed: File exists
```

I found [this Debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=890614) and tried to delete `/var/lib/gdm3/.ICE*` and then restart the system as suggested there, but this returns me to the first state.

Ubuntu version 18.04 LTS

Answer (score -1):

Open ubuntu recovery mode and select boot options on the box then just type on the terminal this line

```
 sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: this is completely generic answer , you neeed to explain why this will help in this situation.

You might have unconfigured packages needing to have configuration applied which could fix this problem,